# What is the most efficient way to escape passed parameters in ssh on a posix compliant shell?

Tags: ssh, escaping, posix, dash-shell

Sometimes you want to escape something reliably before passing it to a shell through ssh. It's curious how difficult this problem seems to be though. :-$

Is there a shorter or otherwise more efficient way of defining this function, so it works with any strictly posix-compliant shell?

```
function sshesc () { printf "%s" "$1" | sed -e "s|'|\'\\\\\'\'|g" -e "s|^|'|" -e "s|$|'|"; }
```

(Simply using echo instead of printf may introduce a bug.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use Perl?

If you need to do this frequently, the Perl module [Net::OpenSSH](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Net%3a%3aOpenSSH) could make your live far easier.

For instance:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new('host');
$ssh->error and die "ssh connection failed: " . $ssh->error;

$ssh->system('ls /*');                      # the remote shell expands '/*'

$ssh->system('echo', '* $how are you! *');  # like calling execvp(3) on the
                                            # remote machine, as if no remote
                                            # shell were involved at all
```

Comment: I could requiere everything. But I only accept usage of basic tools that really are everywhere where ssh is.

Answer (score 1):

To the best of my knowledge, no. That's the shortest shell-quoting implementation I've seen. If you don't want to depend on sed, you can [do it in pure shell](http://gitorious.org/redoconf/redoconf/blobs/master/redoconf/util.sh#line14), but it's a lot more verbose (and slower) that way.

As I understand it, POSIX-compliant shells aren't universally available (hi, Solaris!). If you're willing to lift your requirements to bash instead of dash, you could just say:

```
sshesc () { printf "%q" "$1" }
```

(also works in zsh!)

Answer (score 0):

In Bash, you can do:

```
$ printf '%q' 'echo "argument with    spaces"'
```

In POSIX shell, `%q` of `printf` is not defined. I recently started using a sed script similar to yours:

```
$ printf '%s' 'echo "argument with    spaces"' | sed -e "s/'/'\\\\''/g" -e "1 s/^/'/" -e "$ s/$/'/"
```

The idea is enclose the text in `'`. Then you only have to escape the `'` that were already there.

I also use it as an executable:

```
#!/bin/sed -f

# usage: $0

# make this:
#
#     echo "'special   chars'"
#
# into this:
#
#     'echo "'\''special   chars'\''"'
#

# escape all '
s/'/'\\''/g

# enclose in '
1 s/^/'/
$ s/$/'/
```

Time will show if it's viable.

I've encountered [several](https://github.com/vaeth/push) [projects](https://gitorious.org/redoconf/redoconf?p=redoconf:redoconf.git;a=blob;f=redoconf/util.sh;hb=HEAD#l14) for solving this problem, though most of them seemed too complex for my taste. That's why I ended up making my own.

Comment: bash-completion has a [neat function](https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/2.8/bash_completion#L130) for solving this problem, but it's not compatible with POSIX shell.